# How to reference column of DAX variable?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a DAX variable that contains a table. How can I reference a particular column in that variable?

For example, in the below command, the `EVALUATE` returns an error. But it works if I replace `table1` with `FactInternetSales` (which is the name of the table which contains that column)

```
define var table1=FactResellerSales
EVALUATE ROW("a",COUNTBLANK(table1[SalesAmount]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In DAX you can't use a variable name as with tables that are defined in the model.
What you can do is to use the original table names using the table variable as a filter.
For instance like in the following code

```
DEFINE
    VAR tv1 =
        FILTER( Tab1, Tab1[F1] = "A" )
EVALUATE
ROW( "a", CALCULATE( COUNTBLANK( Tab1[Value] ), tv1 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your DEFINE statement, use TABLE instead of VAR.  Although a variable expression can contain a table, its usage isn't the same as an actual query table.

```
DEFINE
    TABLE table1 = FactResellerSales
EVALUATE
    ROW("a", COUNTBLANK(table1[SalesAmount]))
```

[DEFINE DAX Statement](https://dax.guide/st/define/)

[TABLE DAX Statement](https://dax.guide/st/table/)